# Configure hibernate.cfg.xml in OpenShift RedHat servers

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I'm trying to configure a xWiki server on a OpenShift hosting (Tomcat 6 (JBoss EWS 1.0)). I've never configured a Java server before and I have a issue:

I followed [THIS](http://halfahairwidth.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/how-to-install-xwiki-on-ubuntu.html) tuto on my local Ubuntu and worked. But reproducing the steps in the OpenShift server I can't find the **hibernate.cfg.xml**. Looking for files in the directory tree with hibernate I've found the folder `jbossews-1.0/jbossews-1.0/work/Catalina/localhost/xwiki/WEB-INF/lib/` with the files:

```
hibernate-c3p0-3.6.9.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
```

But nothing similar to hibernate.cfg.xml. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try looking in the parent folder: `jbossews-1.0/jbossews-1.0/work/Catalina/localhost/xwiki/WEB-INF/`

Comment: hibernate.cfg.xml must be in a the classpath, like in WEB-INF/classes folder or in a jar file.

Comment: The file does not exist in any folder

Answer (score 3):

hibernate.cfg.xml is your configuration file for Hibernate, where you specify the dialect, connection driver, url, username, password, etc. of the database.

Example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://host/database</property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Place this file in the Java resources **classpath**.
For detail information look [hibernate.cfg.xml for Oracle](https://code.google.com/p/sarasvati/source/browse/java/trunk/conf/hibernate.cfg.xml.example.oracle?r=1185) or [example by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/)

Answer (score 1):

This is (should be, anyway) an xWiki installation issue. If you are using the WAR file, then when you put the WAR into the tomcat webapps directory, Tomcat normally will expand the WAR into a directory with the same name. In that directory, in the WEB-INF directory, should be the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Typically, here:

`/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/xwiki/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml`

If you have configured your Tomcat to run the WAR without expanding it, then the file will be in the WAR at:

`WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml`

But in this instance you will have to edit the XML file and put it back into the WAR to configure the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and by stracing tomcat I see it looks at the following places, the long one being in the git repository in my openstack gear:

- /var/lib/openshift/518f381fe0b8cd1de2000181/git/tomcat.git/hibernate.cfg.xml
- /usr/share/java/tomcat7/hibernate.cfg.xml

I cannot see any correlation between these locations and the classpath either given in the command line or in catalina.properties. The git repository is the cwd of tomcat. Putting hibernate.cfg.xml there does work for now. But I believe as soon as openstack guys realize how messy is to put the cwd there, they will move it away.